# Efficient ways to code or replace double for-loop (table traversal for another table traversal) in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, for-loop

So now I have two tables, namely `dbo.DEMAND` and `dbo.SUPPLY`, which contain columns including `bidderID`/`vendorID`, `itemID`, `quantity`, `bidPrice`/`sellPrice`, etc. Now I want to regularly (accomplished by using SQL server's proxy) and **automatically match the rows meeting the criteria** (here is my problem) specified below, ordered by `publishTime`, and transfer some information into another table `dbo.DEAL`.

The way I am currently doing is to first `declare @temp table` and insert everything in `dbo.DEMAND` into `@temp`. Then I use `WHILE` to traverse the `dbo.DEMAND` table, for each row use `SELECT TOP 1 XXX FROM` the `dbo.SUPPLY` table when *specific* conditions are met. Finally I `DELETE` the row in the `@temp` table when a traversal in `dbo.SUPPLY` is finished (either `@temp.Quantity` becomes 0, or when no match can be found in the `dbo.SUPPLY` table) and restart with the next traversed row. To be more specific, my goal is to find all *matches* satisfying:

```
{1. @temp.ItemID = SUPPLY.ItemID;
 2. @temp.Bid > SUPPLY.Price;
 3. @temp.LowestDegre > SUPPLY.DegreeN.}
```

one-by-one, first traversing `@temp` ordered by `DEMAND.PublishTime`, and when one *match* is found DO:

```
{1. For the 2 rows (in the two tables), DELETE both rows and the 1 corresponding row in dbo.DEMAND if Quantities are equal, or, 
DELETE the row with smaller Quantity, and SUBTRACT the Quantity in the row with larger Quantity with the smaller one;
2. Add a row in the DEAL table, containing BuyerID, SellerID, ItemID, BidPrice, etc;
3. Redo the MATCH procedure.}
```

Basically in my opinion, this way is same as double-for-loops in C++. However, I've heard that SQL is good at dealing with sets (presumably like we always want matrix operations in MATLAB), and row-wise traversal does take a long time. How can I optimize the algorithm I am currently using?

Sample data:
[image: Sample data from the three tables]

Sample code:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
buyer char(20),
bid float,
quantity smallint,
item char(20),
lowestnew decimal(18,2),
lowestrep decimal(18,2),
pubtime date
);

INSERT INTO @temp(buyer,bid,quantity,item,lowestnew,lowestrep,pubtime)
SELECT BuyerID,Bid,Quantity,ItemID,LowestDegreeNew,LowestReputation,PublishTime FROM DEMAND
ORDER BY PublishTime;
DECLARE @flag int
SET @flag = 0

DECLARE @seller char(20), @buyer CHAR(20), @item char(20), @lowestdegree decimal(18,2), @lowestrep decimal(18,2)

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT buyer, item, lowestnew, lowestrep FROM @temp)

BEGIN

SET @flag = 1

SELECT @buyer = buyer, @item = item, @lowestdegree = lowestnew, @lowestrep = lowestrep FROM @temp

DECLARE @price FLOAT, @quantity SMALLINT

IF EXISTS (select Price, SellerID, Quantity from SUPPLY, SELLER where SellerID = ID and @lowestdegree >= DegreeNew and @lowestrep>=Reputation order by Price)

BEGIN

SELECT TOP 1 @price=Price, @seller = SellerID, @quantity = Quantity FROM SUPPLY, SELLER WHERE SellerID = ID AND @lowestdegree >= DegreeNew AND @lowestrep>=Reputation
IF ((SELECT Quantity FROM DEMAND WHERE SellerID = @seller AND ItemID = @item AND (DegreeNew >= @LowestDegreeNew) AND (Price <= @bid)) IS NOT NULL)
        BEGIN /* TRANSFER INTO NEW TABLE */
```

Footnote: I understand that this could be very easily realized by writing easy C# or Python code in fore-end, but I would just like to see if it's possible to solely do this in the database system.

Comment: Please share the sample data for both the tables (DEMAND and SUPPLY) and expected output for given sample data.

Comment: the `sample code` is incomplete ?

Comment: @Squirrel Yes, it's incomplete because I am still working on the payment system. The `dbo.DEAL` shown in the figure is a demo with only data from these two tables. Basically it's just dealing with 3 cases (>, <, = between the 2 respective quantities in the two tables).

Comment: @Popeye Thanks for reminding me. Have added them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: **No, you must keep using a loop structure.**

I've been there. The joining on "closest day" makes it hard to use a nice set operation. Here's why. Consider those records that have the same equijoin properties (vendor=item etc):

```
Supply: Day 1
Supply: Day 2
Demand: Day 2
```

In this case, you will probably want to join Supply Day 2 with Demand Day 2 due to time difference. But if it was instead:

```
Supply: Day 1 
Supply: Day 2 
Demand: Day 2 
Demand: Day 3
```

You'd probably want Supply Day 1 - Demand Day 2 and Supply Day 2 - Demand Day 3.

This means that each line depends on other lines in a non-easy way (ie: lag/lead window functions won't save you).

This is one of the rare cases you need a cursor/while.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  Yes, that's the problem I am facing ;).  And also when the quantities are not the same, and a new deal can still be reached still with one of the quantity-reduced (let's just call it so) row.  Is there anything other than the loop itself that might be optimized still?  I am running this once per day, so any tiny optimisation might be useful!

Comment: If a demand or supply row's quantity is totally covered, you could mark the row inactive and exclude it from future calculations. I cannot think anything more, except if you paste your entire code so we can micromanage it.

Comment: Thanks.  There're just a few if-else statements in the code block within and I guess few adjustments could be done with them.  Will keep that loop anyway.

Answer (score 0):

SQL works best on set oriented approach and yes it is possible to have a set oriented approach to solve problems like this. Set oriented approach will be more efficient than a looping logic, in almost all cases. Do you have huge volume of bidders and sellers and you are keen on matching them as quickly if yes -> SQL is very good approach here. Are you worried concurrent users flooding the demand and supply tables data and you wish to get your processing through as soon as it comes, SQL approach would be good option.

On another hand, do you envision your rules for matching sellers and buyers to change frequently. Eg: will additional criteria (say two buyers going to bid for same qty and price at about the same time, and one has a higher credit_score than other). Would there be brokers-fee to be considered then matching after your have set up the processing logic. Can there be overriding conditions to a perfectly matched buy and sell order to be made use of. If so, from a maintenance perspective it might be easier to have this kind of processing on rows and looping logic.

As said above, share the actual tables and expected results and will be able formalize the query neeed.

Comment: Thanks!  Yes I'd need to adjust the rules sometimes, so the loop might be a need in this case.  The figure I showed in the main body is just the actual tables & results in my data.  I guess the block within the code, which contains merely if-else statements, could hardly be adjusted much.